# Can anyone explain these two options in Ease US Todo Backup?

Tags: backup, incremental-backup, easeus-todo-backup

I've just come across Ease US Todo Backup (free) and it seems like a godsend ... I've recently had one or two near-disasters with W10 files and in Linux have come the value the peace of mind you get from a well-configured Backintime setup.

I've been experimenting with Ease US for about a day and I've also looked at what documentation I can find ... but I'm still rather puzzled by two options and would really like to find quite a detailed account of the difference between ticking them and not ticking them.

Firstly, for a given backup, into schedule options, "Appoint daily first backup as Full" (or it can be "Differential"). I don't understand what this is about or what it means to tick it or not tick it. This option appears active (not greyed-out), whether you are doing one daily backup per day or multiple incrementals (for example, every 10 minutes). What does it mean if you untick it? What does it mean if you tick it?

Secondly, under Image Reserve Strategy, the option "Don't delete the first image". Again, say you're doing a daily incremental plan, but actually doing an incremental every 10 minutes, and you've set it to only preserve 5 backups maximum, does this mean that, with this ticked, the very first image/snapshot that you create just after midnight will be preserved for the whole of the next 24 hours? Whereas unticked means that in fact your oldest snapshot will be one of how the files were 50 minutes previously?

Generally, with an incremental backup plan of the kind described in the last para, I just don't really get how the full backup/incremental backup business works. At the moment there seem always to be two full backups in that folder, but that may be to do with the fact that I keep editing the plan... it appears that a full backup is then done after you have edited a plan.  Possibly the last full backup is being "mutated" by merging with later incrementals ... but from the time stamp ("last modified"), actually this doesn't appear so.

Any explanation, or link to a full and intricate explanation about such matters, in comprehensible English, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had a long online chat with a senior Ease US "sales engineer" yesterday, who gave me some interesting insights into these two options and the consequences of checking or not checking them.

For example, if you don't click "Don't delete the first image" it is in fact possible that all files involved in your entire backup plan become completely invalid! I could scarcely believe that the Ease US designers would allow such an outcome, so had to double-check with the engineer about this, but it is certainly the case: i.e. your first (full) image gets deleted, leaving only differentials/incrementals, which are rendered useless after the deletion of the first image, as per the Reserve Strategy you have defined (automatic deletion of old images).

I asked how such a design choice could be justified. This was the answer:

"It is not 100% guaranteed that disaster will happen, because users can create many full backup images.
If they have many full backup images, then there is no need to keep the first backup image.
For example, they may create a full backup image every week.
A few weeks later, there are multiple full backup images, then there is no need to keep the first one."

As a general rule, however, it may be advisable to check this "Don't delete first image" by default... unless you really know what you're doing.

Regarding the other option, "Appoint daily first backup as Full/Differential". The explanation for this is that is essentially a way to "override" your "incremental" setting... but only for the first backup action of the day. So you've set things to "incremental"... every 10 minutes. A new day then starts (midnight or whenever), and instead of an incremental image being created referencing the previous day's backups, a new full backup image is created (or differential if you set it that way... which would be quite obscure).

This, it seems to me, is useful for something like a monthly plan: I would feel quite nervous/dubious about relying on incrementals/differentials referencing an image from months and months ago. For most purposes it should hopefully be possible to find time (middle of the night or whenever) to do a full backup once a month. This option enables this sort of plan to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

Having used Easeus ToDo Home for a few years I can tell you that is NOT how "don't delete first image" works. Let's say you tell it to preserve 2 backups and you checked to not delete the first image. When it is time for Easeus to delete older backups, it will do so but will NOT delete the first Full backup. It deletes the incremental or differential backups associated with that first full backup but does not delete the original full backup itself. I have seen this in action and then decided I don't need that original backup and had Easeus go ahead and delete it. I guess there are times you'd want to keep that first full backup, like if it was taken when your system is brand new with freshly installed apps, etc. That would give you a way to start over without having to reinstall your apps.